# Is there any way to check barcode type using barcode number using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, barcode, quaggajs

I tried with `QuaggaJS` for check barcode type using barcode number but its not working.

```
<div class="form-group">
      <div class="label-mini"><span>Barcode</span></div>
      <input
        nz-input
        placeholder="Product Barcode*"
        name="product_barcode"
        formControlName="barcode_number"
      />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="label-mini"><span>Select Barcode Type</span></div>
      <nz-select
        nzPlaceHolder="Barcode Type"
        name="barcode_type"
        formControlName="barcode_type"
      >
        <nz-option nzValue="code128" nzLabel="CODE128"></nz-option>
        <nz-option nzValue="EAN14" nzLabel="EAN14"></nz-option>
        <nz-option nzValue="code39" nzLabel="CODE39"></nz-option>
        <nz-option nzValue="EAN8" nzLabel="EAN8"></nz-option>
        <nz-option nzValue="msi" nzLabel="MSI"></nz-option>
      </nz-select>
    </div>
```

here I have two input field as `barcode_number` *and* `barcode_type` I want if I type any `barcode_number`
it will automatically detect the `barcode_type`

tried Quagga:

```
Quagga.onDetected((result) => {
  const detectedBarcode = result.codeResult.code;
  this.stockForm.get('product_barcode').setValue(detectedBarcode);
  this.barcodeInput.nativeElement.value = detectedBarcode; // Update the barcode input value

  // Automatically select the most similar known barcode type
  const detectedType = result.codeResult.format;

  console.log("result: ", result)
  console.log("detectedBarcode: ", detectedBarcode);
  console.log("detectedType: ", detectedType);

  let similarity = 0;
  let mostSimilarType: string | null = null;
  for (const knownType of this.knownBarcodeTypes) {
    const similarityScore = this.compareBarcodeTypes(detectedType, knownType);
    if (similarityScore > similarity) {
      similarity = similarityScore;
      mostSimilarType = knownType;
    }
  }

  this.stockForm.get('barcode_type').setValue(mostSimilarType);
  this.barcodeInput.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('change')); // Trigger a change event
  Quagga.stop(); // Stop scanning after the first barcode is detected
});

compareBarcodeTypes(detectedType, knownType) {    
 return detectedType 
=== knownType ? 1 : 0;   }
```

nothing is working for me.

I as expect when i type barcode_number it will auto detect the barcode_type and change on select option automatically.